# Half-range Fourier transform of $e^{-ixt}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, complex-integration, fourier-transform, cauchy-principal-value

I'm reading a textbook that has the following sentence:

> Making use of the formula $$\int_0^\infty dt e^{-i x t} = \pi \delta (x) - i \text{P}\frac{1}{x} , $$ where $\text{P}$ denotes the Cauchy principal value...

([Here](https://books.google.ie/books?id=0Yx5VzaMYm8C&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=on%20making%20use%20of%20the%20formula%20where%20P%20denotes%20the%20cauchy%20principal%20value&source=bl&ots=RTXtE3hF4G&sig=iysI62XJQNV8Xw1ayPa6852zP-U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPtq6Mr8DWAhVMKMAKHTECApQQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=on%20making%20use%20of%20the%20formula%20where%20P%20denotes%20the%20cauchy%20principal%20value&f=false) is a link to the page on Google Books.)

Using the Fourier transform $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dt e^{-ixt} = 2\pi\delta(x)$, I can show that the real part of the integral is $$\text{Re}\int_0^\infty dt e^{-i x t} = \pi \delta (x) . $$ But how can I show that the imaginary part is $$ \text{Im}\int_0^\infty dt e^{-i x t} = -i\text{P}\frac{1}{x} , $$ and what does the Cauchy principal value mean in this context? (i.e., principal value of what?)

Comment: $\mathrm{P}\frac{1}{x}$ is a distribution defined by
$$\left< \mathrm{P}\frac{1}{x}, \phi(x) \right> = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} \phi(x) \, dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ixt} \, dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(t) \, e^{-ixt} \, dt$$
where $H$ is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Now we multiply the above identity with $x$:
$$
x \int_0^\infty e^{-ixt} \, dt 
= x \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(t) \, e^{-ixt} \, dt 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(t) \, x e^{-ixt} \, dt 
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(t) \, i \frac{d}{dt} \left(e^{-ixt}\right) \, dt \\
= \{ \text{ partial integration } \}
= -i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H'(t) \, e^{-ixt} \, dt 
= -i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) \, e^{-ixt} \, dt 
= -i
$$

The solutions to the distribution equation $x \, u(x) = 1$ are $u(x) = \mathrm{P} \frac{1}{x} + C \delta(x)$ where $C$ is some constant. Therefore we get
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ixt} \, dt = -i \mathrm{P}\frac{1}{x} + C \, \delta(x)$$

By symmetry reasoning we find that
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-ixt} \, dt = i \mathrm{P}\frac{1}{x} + C \, \delta(x)$$

Thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixt} \, dt = 2C \, \delta(x)$$
but it's well-known that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ixt} \, dt = 2\pi \, \delta(x)$$

Hence we conclude that $C = \pi$ which gives
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-ixt} \, dt = -i \mathrm{P}\frac{1}{x} + \pi \, \delta(x)$$

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit stuck on why $u(x) = \text{P}\frac{1}{x} + C\delta(x)$ is the solution to $xu(x) =1$, though. Could you tell me the reasoning behind that (or point me to a reference)?

Comment: There's some information on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Distribution_theory).

Comment: It's easy to show that $x \mathrm P \frac1x = 1:$
$$\langle x \mathrm P \frac1x, \phi(x) \rangle = \langle \mathrm P \frac1x, x \phi(x) \rangle = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac1x \cdot x \phi(x) \, dx \\ = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \phi(x) \, dx = \int \phi(x) \, dx = \langle 1, \phi \rangle$$
for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R).$

Comment: Then, if $v$ is another distribution satisfying $x \, v(x) = 1$ then we have $x \, (u-v) = 0.$ The only distributions satisfying $x \, w(x) = 0$ are $w(x) = C \, \delta(x)$ so we must have $u-v = C \, \delta.$